# length field in Object Class

Tags: java, arrays, object, variable-length

Sorry if this question have been asked before. I have some doubts regarding length field of Object class. Correct me if i am wrong, Every class impilcitly extends Object class thats why we can access every methods like equals,clone,hashcode etc

So my question is when we create any array for example array of int[] ,foo[] we can access length field of Object class but when we create any object we can not see length variable, why?

Comment: Because `length` isn't defined in `Object`

Comment: Same reason you can't see the asdf variable or the foobar variable.

Comment: So where length field is defined ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Object` class does not define a `length` field, and an `Object` does not have one.

The `length` field is defined for arrays types **only**.  The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) states:

> "In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). [...] The array's length is available as a final instance variable length."

The length field is a defined implicitly.  There is no Java API class declaration where you can see `field` defined.  The `length` field is typically implemented by "JVM magic"; e.g. in the object header.  There is even a special bytecode (`arraylength`) to access it.

> ...  when we create any object we can not see length variable, why?

Why?  Because it doesn't have one!

Comment: So where length field is defined ?

Comment: @FaisalAhmed On the *dynamically* created array class. See [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html): *In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type `Object` (§4.3.2). [...] The array's length is available as a `final` instance variable `length`.*

Comment: Where is it declared?   Nowhere!  It is >>implicit<<.  Where is this defined?  In the JLS; see above.

Comment: Thanks Stephen it was really helpfull

Answer (score 2):

You have to watch out in which direction "inheritance" goes. As you might know, "inheritance" is about defining an "is a" relationship. If a base class defines fields, methods then you might be able to access them in derived classes.

So, in Java, any Integer **is an** Object. Or, any kind of array **is an** Object.

That isn't true for the reverse direction. An arbitrary Object is **not** an array! Meaning: if you create an Object, like with `bar = new Object()` then *bar* doesn't have any of the properties of an array; because *bar* is an Object; but not an array.

Thus you don't find "length" on Object, because Object is **not an array**.

But of course, if an Object is "really" something else, like:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
Object foo = numbers;
```

then you can always do a cast, like:

```
int[] anotherRefToNumbers = (int[]) foo;
```

Edit: just to give a different perspective. If you sit down and draw a circle on a piece of paper; this circle is also a "shape" (or whoever you would call it). But not every shape that you can draw down ... will be a circle.

Comment: can you define this term more clearly sir "Object is not an array".

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding length of an array is size variable that got set when initializing array and its gives actual capacity of the array. As capacity of an array cannot be changed once initialize so `Object []arr = new Object[2]; System.out.length(arr.length)` works fine. The public final field length, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.

Comment: I know this very well brother . My Question was why we cant see length when we create normal objects ? And i have got the answer from Stephen C . And now I am thinking where it is implicitly defined?